# check if user has attribute with certain value in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to show the user a part of the page if he has an attribute with a certain value.

something like this

```
<% if user.st == "Completed" %>
<p>just for him</p>
<% end %>
```

I get undefined method for nil class, how can I select the class in my views directly so I can access the attribute. I cannot use any params

edit: If I do this it works, but I want to check the attribute not if he is signed in

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<% end %>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In place of `user` use `current_user`, I'm assuming that it is for signed in user only

```
<% if current_user.st == "Completed" %>
  <p>just for him</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: super close so I will accept, I used                                                                <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.st == "Completed" %> thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

In your controller:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id]) #or whatever user you want
```

In your view:

```
<% if @user.st == "Completed" %>
  <p>just for him</p>
<% end %>
```